# 1M rows, 1 table, few columns vs 300 tables, 3000 rows, few columns vs 300 columns, 3000 rows, 1 table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have tried looking around for the best way to go about with this problem, but I could not find any previous examples of such problem.

I am building a hyperlocal based internet shopping mall, and the zone is divided into about 3000 zones. Each zone holds about 300 items. They are similar items but can be varied by little for each zone. I need to get the list of "available items" for each zone.

Insertion speed is not a matter, and it will be chiefly getting the items based on the "zone" value. What would be the most efficient way to set up the DB for such instance?

1. 1 table with 1M rows such as

   id  | zone | item | avail
   1   | 1    | 1    | Y
   2   | 1    | 2    | N
   ...
   1262| 4    | 35   | Y
2. 300 tables with 3000 rows such as

   table: zone1
   id | item | avail
   1  | 1    | Y
   2  | 2    | N

   table: zone4
   id | item | avail
   ...
   35 | 35   | Y
3. 1 table with 300 columns (each per item), 3000 rows

   id | zone | item1 | item2 ...
   1  | 1    | Y     | N     ...
   ...
   4  | 4    | Y     | Y     ...

Thanks in advance for any help or any leads I could use so that I could make a decision!

Comment: This question should be migrated to database stack exchange

Comment: Option 1 is more or less what a relational database is built to do efficiently. I can't see a reason to go for either of the other two.

Comment: These are commonly asked questions.  The answers are always:  Do not make lots of tables; and Do not splay an array of stuff across columns.  I would vote to "close" but it only allows me to point to one "dup", not dozens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the limit of opinion based, but here we go;

- Option 1 is most likely what you want.
- Option 2 would give you 300 tables to maintain, so if you need to add a field later you have 300 tables to alter which sounds like a maintainability nightmare. Also, 300 indexes will most likely cache worse than a single bigger one and searching for a specific item in all zones is basically out of the question.
- Option 3 would require you to alter the table structure and queries to add more than 300 items. Also, to be able to find an item by id you'd need SQL looking like `SELECT xx FROM yy WHERE item1=57 OR item2=57 OR ... OR item300=57` which MySQL's optimizer will most likely just give up on.

Comment: That makes it so much clear! Thank you for a kind explanation!

Answer (score 1):

For a Relational Database point of view, you should choose the first option.
 - If one day you have to add a new item or a new zone, you will not have to create a new column or a new table, and the same if you need to delete a item/zone.

But for a NoSQL point of view, you should choose tables like option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use first option. 1M rows, 1 table, few columns .

Answer (score 0):

First option is the best one. DBMSs incur big overhead per table and per row. Plus they were not designed for the case of many tables and many rows.